# what is the right way to work in java, spring and maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am new on Java, and its kind of difficult to me to get into the concepts of Java, I am working with Maven, and Ive read some books but in some give an structure and in others give other structure, the problem of all is that according what Ive read (I want to use Spring) there is a MVC structure, my problem is that I dont know where each thing has to be.. where to set my getters and setters, where my view, where my controllers.. and how to connect them... I am lost.. any reference you could give me or any clue? Id be very glad.

My structure now is

```
src/test/java
src/test/resources
src/main/resources
src/main/resources/META-INF
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you, I would highly recommend the excellent ["Headfirst Design Patterns"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book by headfirst

Comment: After you finish that, I would read some the books they list as references if you want to know more

Answer (score 0):

The `src/test` directory is for unit tests. The `src/main` directory is for your application code. `resources` contains resources (properties files, xml files, etc.) that must be part of the jar, and must be loadable by the classloader (the application classloader in case of `src/main/resources`, and the test classloader in case of `src/test/resources`). Java source files of your application must be under `src/main/java`.